# Removing characters from end of string from character to character

Tags: c#

I have a program that returns the following:

```
PS4      Modern Warfare (2019)
Xbox One Modern Warfare (2019)
PS4      Grand Theft Auto V (5)
Xbox One Grand Theft Auto V (5)
```

I want to remove the parentheses from the end of he strings so they would look like the following:

```
PS4      Modern Warfare
Xbox One Modern Warfare
PS4      Grand Theft Auto V
Xbox One Grand Theft Auto V
```

Currently, the code I have does it however I don't believe it is the best way to go about it as it seems to0 big for what it does.

```
foreach(var i in methodResponse.Response.Data.Results.Where(x => x.CategoryFriendlyName == platform))
{
    if (i.BoxName.EndsWith(")"))
    {
        var arr = i.BoxName.ToArray();
        bool exit = false;

        while(exit != true)
        {
            for (int j = arr.Length - 1; j != 0; j--)
            {
                if (!exit)
                {
                    if (arr[j] != '(')
                    {
                        i.BoxName = i.BoxName.Remove(j, 1);
                    }
                    else if (arr[j] == '(')
                    {
                        i.BoxName = i.BoxName.Remove(j, 1);
                        exit = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        i.BoxName = i.BoxName.TrimEnd();
    }
```

I want to be able to understand an easier way to solve this issue. I know I could use substring however as you can see, the length of the item i want to remove is not always the same.

NOTE: If there are two sets of brackets in the name, I simply want to remove the last set, no other.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Should the space between e.g `Warfare` and `(2019)` be preserved ?

Comment: @Heslacher No, in the code above I trim the name after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply take advantage of the `string.LastIndexOf()` method together with the `string.Substring()` method like so

```
private static string Clean(string value)
{
    return value.EndsWith(")") ? value.Substring(0, value.LastIndexOf('(')).TrimEnd() : value;
}
```

and use it like so

```
foreach(var i in methodResponse.Response.Data.Results.Where(x => x.CategoryFriendlyName == platform))
{
    i.BoxName = Clean(i.BoxName);
}
```

---

Some side notes about the posted code:

- Don't use abbreviations when naming stuff e.g `var arr`
- You shouldn't check like `while(exit != true)` but rather like so `while(!exit)`

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your issue correctly, regular expressions would be sufficient for your case

```
var bracketsRegex = new Regex(@"\s+\(\d+\)");
var result = bracketsRegex.Replace(stringToReplace, string.Empty);
```

In case you have multiple brackets like

> PS4      Modern Warfare (2019) (2018)

You can wrap your regex into brackets end search for one ore matches of it with `+` like below

```
var bracketsRegex = new Regex(@"(\s+\(\d+\))+");
```

You can also change one or more matches to zero or matches with `*`. Consider

> PS4      Modern Warfare(2019) (2018)

The following code matches it

```
var bracketsRegex = new Regex(@"(\s*\(\d+\))+");
```

The same technique allows you to match multiple sequential brackets. Consider

> PS4      Modern Warfare((2019)))

The following code will do the trick

```
var bracketsRegex = new Regex(@"\s*(\()+\d+(\))+");
```

Also you can use online evaluator like [this one](https://regexr.com/) to explore it yourself.

Comment: But what if the string has more than one set of brackets

Comment: I was unsure how exactly more brackets so I've edited my answer to cover more cases. Hope this helps.

Comment: Will the above keep one of the brakcets but remove the other. Say I have the following `(Call of Duty) Modern Warfare (2019)` I want to simply remove the last set of brackets. Will the code provided in this answer do that? I should've made that more clear in the question.

Comment: It will remove only last brackets because `d+` in the regular expression stands for one or more digits. However, in "(2019) Modern Warfare (2019)" both brackets will be removed.

Comment: Also worth mentioning the "negation class", which means you don't have to assume digits: `\([^)]*\)$`: "opening bracket, followed by anything that is *not* a closing bracket, followed by a closing bracket, followed by end-of-line"

Answer (score 0):

I like @Heslacher 's solution, I would add to it a recursive method at the end of Clean so it could handle cases like `(((2015)))` it would also handle cases like `(2015) (5)`. So what I would do is

```
private static string Clean(string game)
{
    string result = value;
    result = game.EndsWith(")") ? game.Substring(0, game.LastIndexOf('(')).TrimEnd() : game;
    if ( result.EndsWith(")"))
    {
        result = Clean(result);
    }
    return result;
}
```